# Is it cheating to use normal KFold for data that is collected over time?

Tags: time-series, cross-validation

I am in doubt when to use strict time-series cross validation and when to use kfold. I have the following situation, which, I believe, is an edge-case between time series and normal data:

I have a **small dataset** which is a couple of thousand rows. The data is collected over time, but I only have a few observations for each shop (specified by `shop_id`) which are note evenly spaced. For the majority of shops, I only have a single observation and therefore, treating each shop as a separate time series is not meaningful. I have feature-engineered the feature called `last_sales` which give the last sales for that `shop_id`. Suppose the first 5 rows look like this:

| time | shop_id | #fetures# | last_sales | sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |  | nan | 8 |
| 1 | 2 |  | nan | 3 |
| 3 | 1 |  | 8 | 4 |
| 5 | 3 |  | nan | 2 |
| 9 | 2 |  | 3 | 2 |

where `#features#` are a number of other features.

I want to predict the `sales` in the future for a known or unknown `shop_id`.

**My question: When validating my model, should I use time-series splitting or is it ok to use kfold ?**
Note, in the end I am not interested in knowing my models performance over time. I am only interested in estimating the model performance in the future.

**My thoughts**:

If I should be very correct, I would think that I should use time-series splitting to take into account that some correlations between a feature and the target may change over time.
On the other hand, it seems silly that when testing the performance at `time = 4` at `shop_id = 1` my model is not allowed to be trained on e.g. the data point `time = 8` at `shop_id = 2`. How bad would it be if I just treat these rows as observations not recorded over time and use normal KFold cross validation utilizing my entire dataset. I emphasize, I want to estimate my model performance for *future* predictions. Not the model performance in the past, where I had fewer data points available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe a time-series does not make sense here if you don't have repeated measurements for all shops. You even wrote most shops have only one observation which would make time-series methods impossible.

What you should do here is proper feature engineering that aggregates the temporal information to one unique shop_id.
Thus, assume the last_sales is measured at different points in time for different shops. You could then include the time difference between today and the time of measurement as a feature. Or even simpler, include the time of last_sales as a dummy variable (eg. time=8 - yes/no).

Another feature could be the difference in sales between the last_sales measurement and the previous sales figures. You can really get creative in the feature engineering process. With the resulting dataset you could then do KFold-cross-validation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This was also how I thought it. So it is ok to have e.g.  t=20 in in my training set and t=2 in my test set? (Both for the same or different shops)

Comment: Well for the same shop this should not happen because my idea was to have each shop_id only once in your dataset. But your concern here is justified. Kfold might lead to data leakage were information from the future is leaking into the training. Thus in your example it is a problem when the information in t=20 for a shop contains information from another shop from  t=2. If you fear that the data from different shops is interdependent you might be safer to restrict your test set to all shops in the most recent time points

Comment: Thanks. I’m wondering if my fears can be tested in any way, or if it is just up to me to decide on my assumptions. I suppose there must be some research on this?

Comment: Your performance on the test set should be better if you have data leakage. Which is not good in this case because it is just a result from a suboptimal data split and not from well-learned model paramters. You could exclude the most recent observations from your dataset as a hold-out test set. If you do cross-validation with the remaining data your performance on the validation set should be much better than on your hold-out test set.